# Jquery RegEx start by plus or minus and numbers only

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to create a regular expression that only allows you to start with a plus or minus symbol, followed by floating numbers. In order to get:

```
+3 return true;
3 return false;
-3. return false;
-3.75 return true;
```

For now, I have this: `var re = /^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/;`. I think I'm close, would you have any idea? thanks in advance

Comment: Just remove the question mark `/^[-+][0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/`

Comment: Or `/^[+-].*/gm`

Comment: @Toto no... it also accept `-.4`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: True, I've just answered for mandatory `+-`

Comment: Actually, there is nothing wrong with `-.4`, it is a valid float value.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use an optional group for catching the decimal part.

```
^[+-]\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `?`, you make the preceding term optional. Remove that and make it compulsory.

```
/^[-+]\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj now I did. Thanks.